# Order of Meta Tag Elements

Tags: meta-tags, tags

I am currently working on a Salesforce page that has Meta tags with elements that are in the order .  For some reason Salesforce is reversing the order of the elements on page rendering to .  Would this break things with products like Google Analytics?  I appreciate any feedback on this question.  Thank you!

Comment: can you share the code snippet or sample code snippet to show what you want to ask

Comment: What meta tags?    Meta elements are not typically shown to users, so I'm not sure how they are "rendering."    I also don't know of any meta tags that need to be in any specific order.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide further details as requested.

Comment: Thanks @AnkDasCo - the tag is <meta name="google-site-verification" content="asdfasdfdfJfAya742m4TdXt__vxwsdf0sdfdas" />.  Salesforce is rendering this as <meta content="asdfasdfdfJfAya742m4TdXt__vxwsdf0sdfdas" name="google-site-verification" /> .  Client claims this breaks it.  I am curious if meta tag element ordering is location sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller, am I supposed to edit the original or create a comment like I have done?

Comment: According to this thread the order does not matter.  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099nOIAQ

Comment: Please edit the original question.